# Getting error when trying to inflate a 2nd layout within fragment onCreateView

Tags: android, view, layout-inflater

I am trying to inflate a view within my onCreateView but I keep getting this error:

```
The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

What I am trying to inflate a view and based on the amount of items in a list to add the view that many times to a linearlayout specified. What am I doing wrong here?

```
View v = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, null);

        for(int i = 0; i < totalItems; i++) {
            TextView itemNumbers = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemNumbers);
            ImageView itemBubbles = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.itemBubbles);
            itemNumbers.setText("0" + String.valueOf(i+1));
            itemBubbles.setTag(i);
            final int finalI = i;
            itemBubbles.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    setupValues(finalI);
                }
            });
            theListItems.addView(v, i);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inflation needs to be in the loop.  YOu're inflating it once, then trying to add it multiple times.  The second time its already been added so it fails.  Each item needs to be inflated individually.

Comment: Thanks I did not know you have to loop on the inflate as well, figured it can re-use itself.

Comment: Nope.  An inflate creates an instance of the view.  If that hadn't thrown an exception you would have just found 1 object overwritten each time.

Comment: Can you try this before addView:  ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).removeView(v);

Comment: Adding the inflater to the loop solved it ARP thanks though

Comment: @ARP that wouldn't help.  He wants to add views for all N items to the view.  Doing that would add only the last.

Comment: Yes, you are rigth